# Acessing a database using zeep

Tags: api, zeep

I am trying to programmatically retrieve information from a database([BRENDA](https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap.php)) using Zeep.

The following is the code.

```
    import zeep
    import hashlib


    wsdl = "https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap/brenda.wsdl"
    password = hashlib.sha256("xx".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    parameters = "xxx," + password + ",ecNumber*{}#organism*{}#".format("2.7.1.2", "Homo sapiens")
    client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl)
    print(client)

    km_string = client.getKmValue(parameters)
```

However, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'getKmValue'
```

Could someone help me with this?

The above code works fine while using SOAPpy library in python 2. However, I couldn't successfully install SOAPpy in python 3, therefore I tried Zeep.

The sample code that shows SOAP implementation is available [here](https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap.php#python)

Comment: Hi there, 

Sorry I don't have a solution but am wondering if you found one? 

I'm having similar issues pulling from BRENDA and SOAPpy isn't working for me so I was hoping to use zeep instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed the webservice. It should work, now. Please have a look at the SOAP documentation on our website.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the update. I tried the sample code given for python3. I couldn't run it successfully. the following error occurs,"self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`  `aise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))`

Comment: I had to make a change in this line of the sample code `password = hashlib.sha256(str("password").encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`, if `encode('utf-8')` is not included I get an encode error. Any suggestion on how to proceed will be really helpful
`

Comment: Yes, the encoding is required. I forgot to update the line in the doc. Will do in a second.

Comment: Does the ConnectionResetError still appear?

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: It's working fine now. Thank you. But the field `"ligandStructureId*"` is not displayed in the output. I could find the values of the other keys, `"ecNumber*1.1.1.1", "organism*Homo sapiens", "kmValue*",
              "kmValueMaximum*", "substrate*", "commentary*", "ligandStructureId*", "literature*")` except `ligandStructureId`. Could you please have a  look at this?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the question itself. Could you please contact me via our contact form?

Answer (score 0):

not the resolution but some hints.

1) with zeep you need to put .service between client and the name of the method. the correct syntax is client.service.getKmValue(parameters) (take a look at [documentation](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/))

anyway for zeep, getKmValue doesn't exists (but it exists on the wsdl schema and SoapUi see it).

you can also try [py-suds](https://github.com/cackharot/suds-py3),

but for some reason i obtain a 403 calling the wsdl.

```
from suds.client import Client
import hashlib
client = Client("https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap/brenda.wsdl")
```